# Spring HATEOAS & HAL: Can I serve just Links but no content?

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

What it says in the title.

I want to serve a root resource that consists only of links to the "lower" resources. It seems that `Resource` as well as `HttpEntity` want an object with some content as their type, so how can I serve just Links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what you conceptually do is returning an empty collection resource with links attached. This can be achieved by this snippet of code:

```
List<Link> links = …
return new Resources<Object>(Collections.emptySet(), links);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out which "Resources" that was and I wanted to return a proper HAL representation in order to make use of "/" as the entry point in HAL Explorer. This worked out for me:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(new RepresentationModel<>()
    .add(linkTo(methodOn(SomeController.class).GET()).withRel("some-rel")));
```